# Assigning function with multiple parameters to a variable

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to figure how to assign a function with multiple parameters to a variable.  When it's just a simple function it works fine:

```
func aFunc(val: Int) {
    print(val)
}

let alias = aFunc
alias(3)
```

But I get an error with this:

```
func handleShip(captain: Pirate, helmsman: Pirate, ship: Ship) {
    print("Handing the ship")
}

func handleShip(helmsman: Pirate, ship: Ship) {
    print("Handling the ship")
}

let handleShipAlias: (Pirate, Pirate, Ship) = handleShip
```

I get:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'handleShip(captain:helmsman:ship:)'

Is there a way to reference `handleShip(captain: Pirate, helmsman: Pirate, ship: Ship)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the function `handleShip(captain: Pirate, helmsman: Pirate, ship: Ship)` is actually `(Pirate, Pirate, Ship)->()` and not just `(Pirate, Pirate, Ship)`.

By changing `handleShipAlias` accordingly, your code compiles just fine.

```
let handleShipAlias: (Pirate, Pirate, Ship)->() = handleShip
```

Functions without an explicit return value default to returning `Void` (which is a typealias to the empty tuple, `()`) and since the type of functions consist of the types of the input arguments plus the return type, you have to include the `Void` return type in the type of your variable representing the function.